# How to send response to Slack with dynamically message options

Tags: slack

I am trying to dynamically populate a message menu based on user selection. however, i am not sure how to send response to slack with the dynamic options. is it through chat.postMessage or chat.update? I tried both and it did not work. this is my code:

```
function usr_access (actionName,response_URL) {
var message = {
"text": "Choose the folder which you need access to",
    "replace_original": false,
        "attachments": [
            {
           "fallback": "Ooops... something went wrong..",
            "callback_id": "DAaccess",
            "attachment-type": "default",
            "actions": [
              {
                "name": "fld_list",
                "text": "Select",
                "type": "select",
                "data_source": "external"
              }
             ]
              }
          ]
   }

   sendMessageToSlackResponseURL(response_URL, message)
}
```

I am receiving below error:

> request
>   ="{\"name\":\"fld_list\",\"value\":\"\",\"callback_id\":\"DAaccess\",\"type\":\"interactive_message\",\"team\":{\"id\":\"xxxxxxxx\",\"domain\":\"xxxxxxxxx\"},\"channel\":{\"id\":\"XXXXXXXX\",\"name\":\"directmessage\"},\"user\":{\"id\":\"xxxxxxxx\",\"name\":\"xxxxxxxxxxxxxx\"},\"action_ts\":\"1545655305.281796\",\"message_ts\":\"1545654125.002700\",\"attachment_id\":\"1\",\"token\":\"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\"}" request =interactive_message ReferenceError: res is not defined
>       at Request.request [as _callback] (SlackApp/events_slack.js:130:12)
>       at self.callback (SlackApp/node_modules/request/request.js:185:22)
>       at emitOne (events.js:115:13)
>       at Request.emit (events.js:210:7)
>       at Request.init (SlackApp/node_modules/request/request.js:231:17)
>       at new Request (SlackApp/node_modules/request/request.js:127:8)
>       at request (SlackApp/node_modules/request/index.js:53:10)
>       at sendDynamicList (SlackApp/events_slack.js:128:2)
>       at app.post (SlackApp/events_slack.js:651:7)

any help or direction would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is resolved now. I tried sending the options is JSON format through res.send() function.(didn't think we can send options that way).